# How to add page numbers during print in the Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing-web-page

I am trying to add page number during printing in the browser using CSS3 @page rule as follows

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 5%;
    padding: 0 0 10%;
}

@page {
   @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
   }
}
```

I have known through the internet this only works for Firefox [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/253824/Print-Page-number-on-each-page-like-1-of-4-print)

I have also tried this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/LeonVFX/9u4e8ajx/) that is only for the paragraph but my page is made with different types of the element like table, div, p etc

How to add page number during printing over any browser

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Copy css and make one file call that css in yourcss and done on header and footer option in chrome advance option give `id="www"` to body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function PrintPanel() {
     var panel = document.getElementById("www");
     var printWindow = window.open();
     printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
     printWindow.document.write('<link href="yourecss.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
     printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
     printWindow.document.close();
     setTimeout(function () {
         printWindow.print();
         printWindow.close();
     }, 1200);
     return false;
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.page{
counter-reset: page;
}
.page .page-number{
  display:block;
  }
.page .page-number:after{
counter-increment: page;
content:counter(page);
}
.page:after{
    display: block;
    content: "Number of pages: " counter(page);
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<span class="page-number">Page </span>
<span class="page-number">Page </span>
<span class="page-number">Page </span>
<span class="page-number">Page </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The above code is specific like '.page-number' but I want to add page number using @page {
                size: A4;
                margin: 5%;
                padding: 0 0 10%;
            }

Comment: use @media print {
  html, body {
width: 210mm;
height: 297mm;
  }

Answer (score -1):

add this to your css. its build into the footer of every page at least in chrome so then it will automatically add page numbers. hopefully this will help somebody. spent hours trying to add pages dynamically...

```
@media print {
    footer {
        display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

[image]